# Swift initializer is inaccessible due to private protection level

Tags: swift, singleton

I'm trying to create a singleton in Swift but I'm getting this error:

> initializer is inaccessible due to private protection level

Here is my code (singleton class)

```
class mySingleton{

    private init() {    }
    static let sharedInstance = mySingleton()
    var numbers = 0

    func incrementNumberValue() {
        numbers += 1
    }
}
```

Here is where I'm calling the singleton:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let single = mySingleton().sharedInstance
}
```

Here is the error:

[image]
Any of you know why or how I can fix this error?

Comment: You've set the initialiser to private, but then you're calling mySingleton(), which is trying to initialize an object of that class. You should change it to mySingleton.sharedInstance

Answer (score 11):

Your line:

```
mySingleton().sharedInstance
```

has a typo. As written you are trying to create an instance of `mySingleton` and then call the `sharedInstance` method on the new instance. That's two mistakes.

What you actually want is:

```
mySingleton.sharedInstance
```

Now this calls the `sharedInstance` type constant on your `mySingleton` class.

BTW - it is expected that classnames begin with uppercase letters. Method and variable names should start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

for using by instance object

class mySingleton{

```
private init() {    }

static let sharedInstance = mySingleton()

var sharedInstanceByInstance: mySingleton{
    return mySingleton.sharedInstance
}
//Usage: mySingleton().sharedInstanceByInstance

// or

func getShared()-> mySingleton{
    return mySingleton.sharedInstance
}   
 //Usage: mySingleton().getShared()
}
```